# how create a .bat file that deletes a file on remote server?

Tags: batch-file

I am pretty new to .bat file concept. I have this daily admin task to remotely login on a server and delete the log file. I created a `delete.bat` file which deletes the desired log file but it works only when it is located locally on that server. If I use the same code (`del D:\Logs1\Logs2\a.txt /p`) on my local machine and schedule (using `at 13:22 \\abc.xyz.com /every:m,t,w,th,f,s,su delete.bat`) to run on remote server, it gives me an error that "the network path was not found".

I searched various websites but couldn't find anything, and if I find something, it's highly VB or some other programming language based solution which I don't understand much.

Any help would be great and thank you in advance.

Comment: I wuold try this on serverfault.com.  Add your platform for source and target machines.

Answer (score 2):

you could try to map that path to a drive (of course you require Write privilege) and delete the files from that drive path.

to add network location (from command line) use: `net use x: \\hostname\folder1\folder2`

here x: can be replaced with any available drive letter.

Comment: hello anantha - when i try to map that file, i dont even see that drive.

Comment: you need to map the drive first & then get the batch file to use the drive for its operations.

Comment: someone helped me out with mapping that drive and then i was easily able to delete the file.